# embed onetomany entity not as a collection, just one entity

Tags: forms, collections, symfony

I am quite new playing and working a little bit with symfony 2 and it`s forms.

My scenario:
I have an account entity and an account_address entity. It´s an oldschool oneToMany relationship between these entites. The main form is the AccountType which embeds the AccountAddressType as an ArrayCollection - this is working, okay. The form renders a lot of AccountAddressTypes on the page, that`s okay because this is a collection, but it is possible to build the same form with only one AccountAddressType ? (the id for this comes from the request)

I just want the same form but with only one embeded Form with the address fields of the given entity. I tried a lot of solutions found in the web, but nothing worked for me.

Example:

- AccountEntity

  - Email
- AccountAddressEntity

  - Firstname
  - Lastname

How to create a form with these fields shown above in only one form?? ( in a form class )

Comment: Are you using Symfony2.0 or Symfony2.1 ?

Answer (score 0):

This example worked in Symfony2.0, not sure about 2.1. You'll get a hidden field in the frontend, with some code inside microdatas. Use it with JavaScript so you can display your form fields.

```
->add('adress', 'collection', array('type'  => new AdressType,
                                              'prototype' => true,
                                              'allow_add' => true));
```

Here is what you should get in the frontend :

```
<div id="randomId" data-prototype="everything about your field, get this value and use it with JavaScript">
</div>
```